# Muiltplie two fields, one with a percentage sign

Tags: javascript, pdf, rounding

I am trying to get a product of two form fields.

Field A * Field B = Field C

example: (5.7%) * 14835 = 846

but when I run the code it comes back "NaN".

I have determined that field C is trying to multiply the % sign as well. How do I get field C to ignore the % sign when performing the calculation?

Field A Custom Calculation Script - this rounds to nearest tenth and adds a "%" sign

```
if (!event.value) event.value = "";

else
event.value = util.printf("%.1f%", event.value);
```

Field B Custom Calculation Script - this rounds to nearest integer

```
if (!event.value) event.value = "";

else
event.value = util.printf("%.0f", event.value);
```

Field C Custom Calculation Script - multiplies fields A and B, rounds to nearest integer and converts Field A into a percentage decimal before multipling

```
var v1 = getField("FieldA").value!="" ? getField("FieldA").value : 0;
var v2 = getField("FieldB").value!="" ? getField("FieldB").value : 0;

event.value = Math.round(((v1/100)*v2) !==0)?Math.round((v1/100)*v2):"";
```

Comment: because the string "5.7%" is NaN (Not a Number)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just take the % sign out of that input value to calculate correctly.  That can be done with replace like so:

```
var v1 = getField("FieldA").value!="" ? getField("FieldA").value.replace(/%/, '') : 0;
```

Comment: That works and the answer comes out fine but when I click out of the text and go to another, Field A turns to "1.$ %", Field C stays the same and Field C turns to "NaN".  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Format field A as Percentage.

The value of the field then has to be the actual factor (such as 0.85 for 85%).

If you want the users to enter percentage numbers, add the following script to the `onFocus` event:

```
event.value = event.target.value * 100 ;
```

and to the `Validate` event:

```
event.value = event.value / 100 ;
```

And that should do it.

Note: I did not verify right now.

Comment: that works great, but I would like the field to be blank until they enter something and to go blank if there isn't a value in there. currently it shows 0.0%.   I added to the validation of the field:

    if (!event.value) event.value = "";

    else
    event.value = event.value / 100 ;